# <script type="text/html" in react not executing (inside Helmet tag of React)

Tags: reactjs

I am new to UI and react. I have a script type = "text/html" and a section of html inside that for one of the pages/ screens. The html section inside  is below.

I have put it in the Helmet section of React, but its not executing as the details shown below is not reflecting in the screen. Any workable approach would be helpful.
Note : I have already the browserRoutes in the App which I cant remove.

```
<script type="text/html" id="table-header-template">
    { `
    <div className="d-flex align-items-end">
                    <h6 className="mb-0">Filters Applied: </h6>
                    <div className="px-2" id="filter-panel"></div>
                    <div className="ml-auto text-right flex-shrink-0">
                        <a id="clear-filter" className="pr-2" href="#">Clear All</a>
                        <button id="download-excel" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"><i className="fh-icon icon-excel fs-xl">&#xe817;</i><span style={dnldExcelStyle}>Download Excel</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown"><span style={sortDrpdwnStyle}>Sort By</span><i className="fh-icon icon-down-arrow">&#xe813;</i></a>
                            <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-md">
                                <div className="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
                                <div className="d-flex flex-row dropdown-item">
                                    <span className="label mr-auto p-2"></span>
                                    <a href="#" className="p-2 btn-outline-success"><i className="fal fa-arrow-from-bottom"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#" className="p-2 btn-outline-success"><i className="fal fa-arrow-from-top"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>      
            </div>

`}
           </script>



return (
  <>
  <Helmet>
 <script type="text/html" id="table-header-template">
        { `
        <div className="d-flex align-items-end">
                        <h6 className="mb-0">Filters Applied: </h6>
                        <div className="px-2" id="filter-panel"></div>
                        <div className="ml-auto text-right flex-shrink-0">
                            <a id="clear-filter" className="pr-2" href="#">Clear All</a>
                            <button id="download-excel" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"><i className="fh-icon icon-excel fs-xl">&#xe817;</i><span style={dnldExcelStyle}>Download Excel</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown"><span style={sortDrpdwnStyle}>Sort By</span><i className="fh-icon icon-down-arrow">&#xe813;</i></a>
                                <div className="dropdown-menu dropdown-md">
                                    <div className="dropdown-divider m-0"></div>
    <div className="d-flex flex-row dropdown-item">
    <span className="label mr-auto p-2"></span>
    <a href="#" className="p-2 btn-outline-success"><i className="fal fa-arrow-from-bottom"></i></a>
    <a href="#" className="p-2 btn-outline-success"><i className="fal fa-arrow-from-top"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
                        </div>      
                </div>
    
    `}
               </script>
</Helmet>
... other code
)
</>
```

Comment: please add a better title for the question to get a simple idea by looking at the title of the question

Comment: What is this "Hemet"/"Hemlet" you are talking about?

Comment: Thanks @DBS for pointing out . It was a typo. I have rectified it to Helmet tag

Comment: I don't see any code that would grab this template and display it on the screen

Comment: @Konrad, The same script was in Helmet tag which I edited. I am not sure how to execute  this as a part of react and that is why I wanted a clean solution / approach for this .